# java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.postValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

**My ViewModel class**

```
@HiltViewModel
class RandomRecipeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val repo: RecipesRepo,
    val app: MyApplication
) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    init {
        getRandomRecipes()
    }

    val randomRecipe = MutableLiveData<Resource<RandomRecipe>>()
    var randomRecipeList: RandomRecipe? = null

    fun getRandomRecipes() {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            try {
                **//Exception in the below line**
                randomRecipe.postValue(Resource.Loading())
                val response = repo.getRandomRecipes()
                randomRecipe.postValue(handleRandomRecipeResponse(response))          
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                if (e is IOException) {
                    randomRecipe.postValue(Resource.Error("Turn on Internet"))
                } else {
                    randomRecipe.postValue(Resource.Error("Conversion Problem"))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleRandomRecipeResponse(response: Response<RandomRecipe>): Resource<RandomRecipe> {
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { newResponse->
                if(randomRecipeList == null) {
                    randomRecipeList = newResponse
                }else{
                    val oldRecipeList = randomRecipeList?.recipes
                    val newRecipeList = newResponse.recipes

                    oldRecipeList?.addAll(newRecipeList)
                }
                return Resource.Success(randomRecipeList ?: newResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(msg = response.message())
    }
}
```

**RandomRecipe(MainActivity)**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RandomRecipes : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: RecipesRandomBinding
    lateinit var randomRecipeViewModel: RandomRecipeViewModel

    lateinit var randomRecipeAdapter: RandomRecipeAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = RecipesRandomBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
        randomRecipeAdapter = RandomRecipeAdapter()
        randomRecipeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[RandomRecipeViewModel::class.java]

        binding.apply {
            randomRecyclerView.adapter = randomRecipeAdapter
            randomRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        }


        randomRecipeViewModel.randomRecipe.observe(this, Observer { resource->
            when(resource) {
                is Resource.Loading -> showProgressBar()
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    resource.msg?.let {
                        Snackbar.make(binding.randomRecipeActivity, it, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("Refresh"){
                                randomRecipeViewModel.getRandomRecipes()
                            }.show()
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    resource.data?.let {  recipe ->
                        randomRecipeAdapter.differ.submitList(recipe.recipes.toList())
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    private fun showProgressBar() {
        binding.progressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    private fun hideProgressBar() {
        binding.progressbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

**Resource class**

```
    sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val msg: String? = null
) {
    class Loading<T>(): Resource<T>()
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(msg: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data, msg)
}
```

**Error**
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.postValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.recipe.viewmodels.RandomRecipeViewModel$getRandomRecipes$1.invokeSuspend(RandomRecipeViewModel.kt:45)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.example.recipe.viewmodels.RandomRecipeViewModel.getRandomRecipes(RandomRecipeViewModel.kt:33)
at com.example.recipe.viewmodels.RandomRecipeViewModel.(RandomRecipeViewModel.kt:26)
at com.example.recipe.util.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.randomRecipeViewModel(DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:442)
at com.example.recipe.util.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.access$1800(DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:419)
at com.example.recipe.util.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:477)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:97)
at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:119)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at com.example.recipe.RandomRecipes.onCreate(RandomRecipes.kt:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of the `init` block and property initializers:

```kotlin
val randomRecipe = MutableLiveData<Resource<RandomRecipe>>()
var randomRecipeList: RandomRecipe? = null

init {
    getRandomRecipes()
}
```

Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) is pretty clear on that topic:

> During the initialization of an instance, the initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with the property initializers.

The `randomRecipe` was simply not initialized at the time when the `getRandomRecipes` method was executed.